# Using SQL Server Agent in DataGrip

Tags: sql-server, datagrip, sql-server-agent

I've been testing DataGrip as a SQL IDE recently and I really like it.  Particularly I decided to test it because of the multiple database type support.

One issue that I am having, and that is forcing me to keep SSMS open, is the SQL Server Agent.  When developing I use it quite a bit to execute jobs from the agent.  I cannot seem to get the SQL Server Agent to show up in the DB window in DataGrip (or anywhere else for that matter).  Is this even possible?  If not then this might be a deal breaker from me when working with SQL Server.

I have tried googling all the possible ways this question could be asked, and I've walked through the 'Connecting to SQL Server' instructions on the JetBrains site for DataGrip.

Comment: No Datagrip is mainly designed for writing queries, it's not really meant for management. It doesn't even do query plans properly. I keep both open.

Comment: hmm I get that, it just seems to defeat the purpose a bit. I think people who use SQL Server would more readily adopt this as a primary IDE if they would only support this feature.  There was one plugin that seems to have done this but it doesn't support the current version of DataGrip.

Comment: DataGrip team has ![an issue about SQL Server agent](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2423)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research and even reaching out to JetBrains themselves, it appears this is not planned to be supported anytime soon.  It's kind of a shame this is the case, but I suppose there's only so much you can do.  There is a plugin for this, but it will only work on 2019 versions of DataGrip, not the current 2020 versions.  Here is the link for anyone using an older version of DataGrip that wants to incorporate this feature into their IDE.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13473-sql-server-administration-tool